# Cascading Combo Box on Form not allowing any selection

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a form with 2 different cascading combo boxes set-up. Each has one box that requeries a second combo box after a selection is made. The second combo has criteria to only show values that correspond with the selection chosen in the first box.

The `AfterUpdate()` event is with a macro:

`Requery`

`Control Name: StageID`

Example: ProjectType is box 1, with choices of either Capital or Development. The selection then influences the drop down on the Stage combo box. The table structure that they are generated from is 3 fields: "StageID", "StageName" and "ProjectType", therefore all 3 fields are in the Stage combo box with only the stage name being shown and the "ProjectType" being linked using criteria:   `[Forms]![Project Update]![ProjectType]`

The SQL are as follows

ProjectType - Value List

Stage -

```
SELECT Stage.StageID, Stage.StageName
FROM Stage
WHERE (((Stage.ProjectType)=[Forms]![Project Update]![ProjectType]));
```

Business -

```
SELECT Business.BusinessID, Business.Business
FROM Business;
```

Problem Statement -

```
 SELECT ProblemStatements.ProblemStatementID, ProblemStatements.ProblemStatement
 FROM ProblemStatements
 WHERE (((ProblemStatements.BusinessID)=[Forms]![Project Update]![Combo493]));
```

The control sources for the Stage and ProblemStatemenet fields are from a table named ProjectList which has the fields ProjectID which is filtering the form as well as the fields ProblemStatementID and StageID. The business and ProjectType fields however have a control source from the "ProblemStatement" table and the "Stage" table respectively.

The combo boxes update fine, however after it is requeried/the Project type is changed I am unable to select a new Stage. If I change it back to the original Project Type the original stage is automatically chosen but I'm unable to select a different one. Also, I can change the stage before I select a projecttype (before the first requery).

I'm having the exact same problem with a Business/ProblemStatement combo, the only difference is the table structure.

`Table 1: Business, fields: BusinessID and Business`

`Table 2: ProblemStatements, fields: ProblemStatementID, BusinessID, ProblemStatement`

The SQL for the query that is generating the form is as follows:

```
SELECT ProblemStatements.BusinessID, Business.Business,
ProjectList.StageID, Stage.ProjectType, ProjectList.ProjectID,
ProjectList.ProjectTitle, ProjectList.SiteID, ProjectList.CodeName,
ProjectList.Type, ProjectList.RegionalGlobal, ProjectList.Category,
ProjectList.Status, ProjectList.StartDate, ProjectList.Sensitivity,
ProjectList.ProblemStatementID, ProblemStatements.ProblemStatement,
ProjectList.Attachment, ProjectList.Keywords, ProjectList.Tracking

FROM (Stage RIGHT JOIN (Site RIGHT JOIN (ProblemStatements RIGHT JOIN
ProjectList ON ProblemStatements.ProblemStatementID =
ProjectList.ProblemStatementID) ON Site.SiteID = ProjectList.SiteID) ON
Stage.StageID = ProjectList.StageID) LEFT JOIN Business ON
ProblemStatements.BusinessID = Business.BusinessID;
```

I am using the same method on a form that is used strictly for new data entry and it works fine. The form its not working on is used for updating existing records.

Comment: One thing to note, it works fine and saves the changes when the first combo box is unbound (how it is on the new data entry form), however then when the form is opened it doesn't automatically prefill the fields with the current values which is required.

Comment: It seems like there's something funky with the control sources. Could you post the SQL code for your two combos? The `AfterUpdate()` code might be useful as well.

Comment: The control source is for both the controls that are giving the trouble (Stage and Problem Statement) are being taken from a table "ProjectList". The "ProjectList" table has many fields including Project ID (which is used as a filter for the form), StageID and ProblemStatementID. 
The SQL statements are as follows:
` SELECT Stage.StageID, Stage.StageName`
 `FROM Stage`
`WHERE (((Stage.ProjectType)=[Forms]![Project Update]![ProjectType]));`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the SQL. Label which combo boxes they control. That saves other users from searching comments.

Comment: If the combo boxes are bound, you are ending up with situation where the current value of the field is invalid for the combo box. This can get pretty messy. Your best bet is to use unbound combo boxes and hidden text fields for the actual bound values and use event handling to manually sync the combo boxes with your record values.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! I unbound the first combo box (Project Type and Business) and set their default value to hidden fields that were bound to the proper fields. Unbinding the fields allowed me to select the values no problem and setting the default value made sure that when the form was loaded the fields displayed the correct values (no longer were blank).